# AEM workflow session logout

Tags: workflow, aem

Should we close workflow session provided in parameters of execute method while implementing a workflow process?
And one more query related to it is that who create these session objects?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://antonyh.co.uk/2012/01/day-cq5-development-best-practices-html/) article, you should close sessions ONLY if you opened them. So in your case you should NOT close the session.

In this case, session object has been created by CQ.